# ReactJs with media queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries

I'm developing a a base site app for a multi-function site. So in this moment I'm developing only the responsive frame where the app will go. I want the page to have a header and 3 columns (2 lateral columns for ads and a middle column for the application).
I want the lateral columns to appear only in resolutions above 850px.
So I have the following code:

App.js:

```
<...imports, etc ...>
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='divAds'>
                <VerticalAd />
                <div className='divMiddle' >
                    <HorizontalAd />
                    <div className="App" >
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                            <Redirect to="/" />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <VerticalAd />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

and in VerticalAd component I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import VerticalSun from '../../img/sun-vert.jpg';
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import './verticalAd.scss'

export const VerticalAd = () => (
    <div className='divVad'>
        <Image src={VerticalSun} rounded alt="Vertical Ad" />
        <Image src={VerticalSun} rounded alt="Vertical Ad" />
        <Image src={VerticalSun} rounded alt="Vertical Ad" />
    </div>
```

which created this page structure: [image: Base page]

So I want the lateral columns to disapear in mobile screens so I had the following css to VerticalAd.scss:

```
.divVad {
    @media (min-width: 850px) {
        display: block;
    }

    @media (max-width: 849px) {
        display: none;
    }
    
    img {
        width: 10em;
        height: 50em;
    }
}
```

But the vertical columns won't disapear in lower resolutions. What am I doing wrong ?

I tried to move @media queries to App.scss but didn't work also.

I'm testing this using Chrome developer tools's responsive test.

**Edit**

The problem was developer tools. ASAI tested it by sizing the whole browser window it worked. Sorry.
But anyway... @Samathingamajig answer's was useful and I have accept it. Sorry any inconvenience.

Comment: Write it this way :  `@media only screen and (min-width: 850px)` and check?

Comment: Didn't work. Same thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the media queries the wrong way around; media queries go outside, selectors go inside:

```
.divVad {
    img {
        width: 10em;
        height: 50em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 850px) {
    .divVad {
       display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 849px) {
    .divVad {
       display: none;
    }
}
```